# ¿Cómo hacer que un div que tiene scroll vertical muestre la última parte de éste al cargar la página en html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un div `<div class="contenedor">Contenido...</div>` al cual le apliqué los estilos css:

```
.contenedor {
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

para que éste tenga un scroll y un alto máximo del tamaño especificado, cada que recargo la página éste me muestra el scroll en la parte superior, osea muestra el contenido que ésta arriba. Necesito que me muestre al cargar la página o cuando yo lo requiera que se muestre la parte final del contenedor, osea que el scroll esté hasta el final.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con esto

```js
var objDiv = document.getElementById("contenedor");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

```css
#contenedor {
    border: 1px solid red;
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">Contenido...
Contenido...
Contenido...
Contenido...
Contenido...
Contenido...
Contenido...
Contenido...
Contenido...
Contenido...
Contenido...
Contenido...
Contenido...
Contenido...
Contenido...
Contenido...
Contenido...
Final
</div>
```

Donde jugamos con la propiedad [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) para asignarle el desplazamiento del scroll y el atributo [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) para conocer la altura del contenido actual.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias; me sirvió.